# What is going on here? with for people in people print people loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
people = ['mago','pipa','john','mat']
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)


mago
pipa
john
mat
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)


m
a
t
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)


t
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)


t
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)


t
>>> for people in people:
    print(people)
```

Comment: change list name to `peoples` and then `for people in peoples: print(people`

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop does not create a new scope for the index; you are overwriting the list `people` with the loop index `people`.

A `for` loop is almost syntactic sugar for the following code:

```
# for people in people:   # iter() is called implicitly on the iterable
#    print(people)
people_itr = iter(people)
while True:
    try:
        people = next(people_itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(people)
del people_itr
```

So although you have a reference to the list originally referenced by `people`, the *name* `people` is constantly updated to reference one *element* of that list. When you run your second loop, `people` is now a reference to the *last* string in the list. The third and subsequent loops represent a fixed point; an iterator over a string returns successive 1-character strings, so you quickly reach a point where the string is its own only element.

With your example, `people` is bound to `"mat"`, not your list, after the first loop. After the second (and third, and fourth) loop, `people` is bound to `"t"`.

You can see the same thing by chaining calls to `__getitem__` (i.e., `[-1]`):

```
>>> people[-1]
'mat'
>>> people[-1][-1]
't'
>>> people[-1][-1][-1]
't'
>>> people[-1][-1][-1][-1]
't'
```

Comment: If it did, you would then need some way to refer to variables from the enclosing scope in the event you shadowed a name.

Comment: If only we had a keyword like `nonlocal` ;-)

Comment: `nonlocal` wouldn't help here, unless you significantly changed its semantics. `nonlocal p` means that `p` here is the same object that `p` in the enclosing scope refers to; it doesn't let you access a shadowed name.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood you then -- why would you need to refer to a shadowed variable from an enclosing scope? You can't do that currently (since shadowing a variable simply redefines it)

Comment: If a new scope did not allow access to shadowed names, then you may as well make sure to use unique names, but then there's no real need for a new scope. You seem to be saying that the loop index should simply not exist after the loop exits, but then you can't use a loop to search a container by exiting once the index is equal to the desired value.